# Php Function how to turn integer into varchar on the output

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new here and also just started learning to program.

I'm creating PDF file from my web project, there is 1 integer column in my table which the value is 0,1,2. The output in PDF is number but I want to change the number into text.

example if the "Status" is 1 the output is "Approved" if "Status" is 2 the output is "Declined", and if the "Status" is 0 the output is "on the process"

```
  function fetch_data()  
  {  
  $output = '';  

  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "system");  

  $sql = "SELECT Status from tabel";  

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {       
  $output .= '<tr> 
                <td>'.$row["Status"].'</td>  
              </tr>  
                      ';  
  }  
  return $output;  
  }
```

Comment: Make another table with statuses and their values. Make a join with that table in the select query on the basis of status. In this way you can also store further statuses and their values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an array of the statuses is fastest and cleanest:

```
$status = [
   'On Process',
   'Approved',
   'Declined'
];

echo $status[$row["Status"]];
```

Using your code:

```
function fetch_data()  {  
  $status = [
     'On Process',
     'Approved',
     'Declined'
  ];
  $output = '';  
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "system");  
  $sql = "SELECT Status from tabel";  
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {       
      $output .= '<tr> 
                <td>'.$status[$row["Status"]].'</td>  
              </tr>';  
  }  
  return $output;  
}
```

The best way to do this would be to have a second table in your database that maps the numerical status to the status text. Then you could just do a JOIN to get them in your query and simplify your code:

Table `statusText` :

```
StatusId | StatusName 
---------|-----------
    0    | On Process
    1    | Approved
    2    | Declined
```

New code :

```
function fetch_data()  {  
  $output = '';  
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "system");  
  $sql = "SELECT t.StatusName from table s JOIN statusText t ON s.Status = t.StatusId";  
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {       
      $output .= '<tr> 
                <td>'.$status[$row["StatusName "]].'</td>  
              </tr>';  
  }  
  return $output;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Declare An Array Set Like This :

```
$status_array = array(1=>'Approved', 2=>'Declined', 0=>'on Process');
```

and use the array as :

```
$status_array[ $row["Status"] ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup list, simply:

```
$statuses = [
    'On Process',
    'Approved',
    'Declined'
];
```

And

```
$output .= '<tr> 
    <td>' . $statuses[$row["Status"]] . '</td>  
</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

One good approach is to create a normal array or an associative array that stores the numbers: 0, 1, 2 and the text each represents. That way you can always extend your program to include more status codes. In `PHP`, you can create a normal array like this:

```
$statuses = array(
    "On Process",
    "Approved",
    "Declined"
);
```

If you use a normal array, then you can access your desired text by just using `$statuses[$status_number]` so that to display `Declined`, you just type `$statuses[2]`. However, using a normal array may cause you problems when you want to extend this functionality to include more statuses especially when you want to change the arrangement of the statuses, you will have to change it everywhere it appears in your program.
Using an associative array, it would look like this:

```
$statuses = array(1=>'Approved', 2=>'Declined', 0=>'On Process');
```

There is really no advantage using associative array since you are using integers as the key, it's really not different since you access the values with the same method as in a normal array.

Comment: **John Conde**'s answer would have the best solve the problem of extending your program to include more statuses

Answer (score -1):

Since your tag specifically ask for `if` statements:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){       
        $result = "";

        if($row["Status"] == 0){
           $result = "On Process";
        }

        if($row["Status"]){
          $result = "Approved";
        }

        if($row["Status"]){
          $result = "Declined";
        }

       $output .= '<tr><td>'.$result.'</td> </tr>';  
    }  
       return $output;  
   }
```